# Remapping Component Selection Hotkeys

Tags: modeling

Is there a way I can map verts / edges / faces to my <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> keyboard buttons like Modo? Having to go through a pie menu to select different component modes really slows me down a lot. Can't seem to find them under the user preference/input menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and select *Vertex*, *Edge* or *Face* from the popup menu, which will appear under the mouse. As far as I know, this is the fastest way to switch.

**Update for 2.8**: This function is now available by default when pressing <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd>. To remap this back to the original behavior see this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112320/2-8-mesh-select-mode-hotkey-changed).