# 2.8 mesh select mode hotkey changed

Tags: edit-mode

The hotkey for mesh select mode (vertex, edge, face) while in edit mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> has been reassigned in 2.8. Is there another hotkey assigned for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unreleased experimental development software

Comment: Its just gone Alpha,...I'd say keep it open.

Comment: Now has release candidate

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1,2 and 3!

I found them by looking in the User Prefs and searching for "mode", got the feeling I will be searching here quite a lot.

[image]

Comment: My problem with 1,2,3 is that if you are on mackbook or laptop w/o numpad, those keys switch views. so, using them as a default select_mode isn't an option.

Comment: Additionally you can hold shift to combine these selection modes.

Answer (score 10):

Blender 2.80 is taking a minimal shortcut approach, that is, it is removing many existing shortcuts in the default setup.

The idea is that we have a huge number of shortcuts assigned to tasks that even long terms blender users do not know about, some tasks even have multiple key combinations assigned to them, for example you can open a file with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> or you can press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

You can either start with this minimal setup and add shortcuts that make sense to you, which is now easier as there are less keys with tasks pre-assigned, or you can go back to the old 2.7x shortcuts.

When you start blender you can choose which keymap to use in the splash screen.

[image: 2.80 splash screen]

You can also change the keymap in the preferences.

[image: keymap in preferences]

Once you choose a keymap to use, you can save your settings so that it is used each time you start blender.

Answer (score 10):

I am also using a laptop with **Emulate Numpad** turned on. Adding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier to <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd> did not do anything. I discovered that I needed to remap the numbers themselves:

1. Click the field with the number <kbd>1</kbd> in it.
2. Press the <kbd>1</kbd> key on your keyboard.

Because you have *Emulate Numpad* turned on, you will see it change to <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>:

[image: Make sure the hotkey says Numpad1]

Answer (score 7):

You can also just add that specific shortcut back with the Call Menu command: `VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_mode`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use ctrl+1/2/3 for vertex select, edge select, face select and shift+1/2/3 to add more than one selection mode

Comment: Ctrl has no effect. 1/2/3 will toggle between the modes, and shift + 1/2/3 will add to the existing mode(s).

Comment: Alt+1, Alt+2, and Alt+3 are available.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem for a long time, by now I found the way

Preferences/Keymap/Mesh/

the first three options map the vertex, edge, face

there is  1 2 3 already there, but my keypress didn't work,
so just repress the key you want to map by hand, and you will find
the number changed to Numpad 1, Numpad 2, Numpad 3,
in fact, I press the top line Numbers.
and you will lose the scene look angle default hotkey on the real Numpad.

the cause I think is the 2.8 can't recognize my keyboard Numpad number or not.

May just my own problem.

good luck.

Answer (score 2):

i used this way for personal pie menu.
In this case:

1. find by name on preference/keymap >> select mode;
2. change the name of an existing shortcut with wm.call_menu (it will automatically made a menu)
3. press ctrl + tab to set your shortcut;
4. add this line on the name form: VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_mode

I hope it help...

[image]

Comment: AMAZING, exactly what I've been looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch back, you could go to do so by going to *Edit > Preferences > Input*, and then deselecting *Emulate Numpad* and select *Default to Advanced Numeric Input*.

This will let you use 1 2 and 3 for what you want to use them for (vertices, edges and faces select in Edit mode).

[image: Screenshot]